# AVaudioplayer audio player progess as Uislider crashes

Tags: xcode, swift

So I'm making a basic music app that plays a song. It works fine until I scrub the song manually but when I add the NStimer to scrub it automatically with the song playing, the app crashes! Help will be appreciated!

```
    
    var player:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()


    @IBAction func play(sender: AnyObject) {

        player.play()
    }


    @IBOutlet var volumeSlider: UISlider!

    @IBAction func adjustVolume(sender: AnyObject) {

        player.volume = volumeSlider.value
    }

    @IBOutlet var scrub: UISlider!


    @IBAction func adjustScrub(sender: AnyObject) {

        player.currentTime = NSTimeInterval(scrub.value)
    }

    @IBAction func pause(sender: AnyObject) {

        player.pause()
    }


    @IBAction func stop(sender: AnyObject) {

        player.pause()
        do {

            try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("001 JIS GALI MEIN TERA GHAR - KATI PATANG", ofType: "mp3")!))


        }catch{

            //didnt work
        }



    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        do {

    try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("001 JIS GALI MEIN TERA GHAR - KATI PATANG", ofType: "mp3")!))

            var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: Selector("updateSlider"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

            scrub.maximumValue = Float(player.duration)

        }catch{

            //didnt work
        }

        func updateSlider() {
            scrub.value = Float(player.currentTime)

        }


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()   

    }    
}
```

Comment: What error do you get when this crash occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Few things: why are you re-defining `player` in the `pause()` method? You already did that in `viewDidLoad()`. And, by the way, you have a function definition inside `viewDidLoad()`, check that too.

On the other hand, I think you can have another issue related to the way you're using try. Instead of:

```
do {

            try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("001 JIS GALI MEIN TERA GHAR - KATI PATANG", ofType: "mp3")!))

            var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: Selector("updateSlider"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

            scrub.maximumValue = Float(player.duration)

        }catch{

            //didnt work
        }
```

you have to use it like

```
do {
        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("001 JIS GALI MEIN TERA GHAR - KATI PATANG", ofType: "mp3")!))

        var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: Selector("updateSlider"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        scrub.maximumValue = Float(player.duration)

    } catch let error as NSError {

        print(error)
    }
```

Or, if you don't want to use the whole `do - try - catch` structure, you have the possibility of using the keyword `try!`. Then your code will look like this:

```
        player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("001 JIS GALI MEIN TERA GHAR - KATI PATANG", ofType: "mp3")!))

        var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: Selector("updateSlider"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        scrub.maximumValue = Float(player.duration)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

you can use [JukeBox](https://github.com/teodorpatras/Jukebox) Player for streaming local and remote audio files. that basically use AVAudioPlayer for playing songs but it helps you in managing basic functions like play, pause, slider tracking ,next ,previous.